Grammar analysis of adverb inbetween relative clause and modified noun
What I mean with the title are these types of relative clauses:

寝る少し前


雨の止むまさにその切れ間

少し and まさに seem to be modifying 前 and 切れ間, respectively, which at first glance seems unusual for adverbs. How can one analyze these types of relative clauses? In what registers are they permissible?

Why do you think it’s unusual? I think 少し前 is very commons way of saying. Emphasizing 間 with まさに is also not rare I think.
